# Is there a way to skip pytest if fixture setup or teardown fails?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Is there a way to skip test if any part of the fixture throws an exception? I'm using a third party fixture that tends to error-out randomly during teardown, so I'm trying to wrap my tests so that if the random error is thrown (note: the tests are not failing, the fixture is erroring out), `pytest` simply skips the tests.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import functools
import numpy as np
import pytest


def handle_fixture_errors(f):
    """decorator for wrapping test function in try/catch"""
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print('about to run my test')
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
            print('never reached')
        except Exception as e:
            msg = 'Ignoring fixture exception ' + str(e)
            pytest.skip(msg)

    return wrapper

@pytest.fixture()
def failing_fixture(request):
    """fixture fails on teardown"""
    x = np.linspace(10, 20, 100)
    y = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 5))
    def teardown():
        print('fixture teardown is failing')
        z = x.T.dot(y)
    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return x


@handle_fixture_errors
def test_matmul(failing_fixture):
    """original test function"""
    print('hey this is my test')

    k = failing_fixture
    assert len(k) == 100
```

The issue is that the test itself is not throwing the exception, it's the fixture that's throwing the exception, so the `try/catch` is not capturing the test's exception and preventing the ".E" from resulting in the test summary. My test output still look like this:

```
========================================================= ERRORS =========================================================
____________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of test_matmul ____________________________________________

    def teardown():
        print('fixture teardown is failing')
>       z = x.T.dot(y)
E       ValueError: shapes (100,) and (1000,5) not aligned: 100 (dim 0) != 1000 (dim 0)

test_fake.py:25: ValueError
-------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------
about to run my test
hey this is my test
------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout teardown ------------------------------------------------
fixture teardown is failing
================================================ short test summary info =================================================
ERROR test_fake.py::test_matmul - ValueError: shapes (100,) and (1000,5) not aligned: 100 (dim 0) != 1000 (dim 0)
=============================================== 1 passed, 1 error in 0.18s ===============================================
```

I don't want to skip the setting up or tearing down the fixture, I just want to have the test considered "skipped" entirely (or at the very least, silenced or `pass`ed). Thx for the help!

Comment: Just comment it out

Comment: ... no I need the fixture to run other tests. `failing_fixture` only represents the third party fixture that works *most* of the time but fails randomly, but in real life it's buried in another codebase. Need to be able to skip the test when the fixture does fail but still use the fixture when it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's ever reasonable to skip a test like that; either you want it or you don't!

If you have *intermittent* tests (or rather the fixture in this case), consider re-running 'em, perhaps after a short delay or some check (network traffic too high? try again off peak hours)

pytest suggests a few plugins for this which look high-quality, and can add delays, etc. between runs
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/flaky.html#plugins

If you know exactly where it will fail, consider re-trying several times on your own before your code gives up or hands control back to pytest, by designing your logic in some loop

```py
for _ in range(10):  # attempt call 10 times
    time.sleep(10)  # yuck
    try:
        foo = flakey_call()
    except Exception:
        continue  # failed: try again, consider different waits
    if hasattr(foo, "bar"):
        break  # successfully got a valid foo
else:  # did not find and break
    raise Exception("the foo had no bar!")
```

It may also be possible to mock out the 3rd-party fixture optionally (I would caution away from this, as it can lead to the fixture never working), or per-run

Contrive some logic to get the 3rd party logic's response, potentially in-fixture re-running it until it does what you want..

Then either

- serialize it into some useful form for you and save it for future runs (for example parquet if it's some data collection)
- pickle the object (I would only ever do this for a single run where there are many calls, but only needs to succeed now)